# TS4023: Exported variable, has or using name 'internal.Transform' from external module 'stream' but cannot be named

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript2.0

I am seeing this arcane TypeScript error:

> TS4023: Exported variable, has or using name 'internal.Transform' from
>   external module 'stream' but cannot be named.

Does anyone know what this actually means?

I see this issue on Github, trying to decipher it:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5711

[image]

Answer (score 7):

### What is going on?

Typescript is unable to explicitly name the type of `getTapJSONParser` or of anything this method exposes to the outside world. There are two reasons for this: Either you do not include the definition for `internal.Transform` or that definition is shadowed by a local definition. In your example, most probably the first of the two possibilities causes you trouble.

Now, in the error message it looks like typescript correctly determined the type, why does it still issue an error message? For exporting anything, typescipt needs to be able to reference the type directly. It basically knows which type it wants to use, but just cannot reference it, since it does not add any additional import statements. That means that if adding a type definition adds a type that is not imported, the naming fails, causing this error message. An easier way to think about this is: If you would add a type definition by hand to your exported stuff, would that cause an error because you didn't explicitly import the type definitions you used? If yes, you need to add those imports even if you want typescript to figure out the type.

### How to fix this?

First, verify that you do not have any type that shadows `internal.Transform`. If this is not the case, `import { Transform } from "stream";` (or just import everything that stream exports, might be easier if you use more than just `Transform`).